# Letter Counter (with substring rather than the usual atChar() method)

Tags: java

I have a programming challenge and I'm a bit stuck as to how to get it to work.
The challenge is as follows:

Write a program that asks the user to enter a string, and then asks the user to enter a character. The program should count and display the number of times that the specified character appears in the string.

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class F***Around 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word, character, test;
    int c = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
    word = keyb.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a character: ");
    character = keyb.nextLine();

    for(int x = 1; x <= word.length(); x++)
    {
        test = word.substring(1, 2); 
        if (test.equals(character))
        {
            c += c;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(c);
}
}
```

It always returns a 0 at the end and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 changes needed:

1. Use the iteration variable `x` to actually loop through the string. Currently, you are hard coding the substring to be compared, so the loop is virtually useless.
2. Increment `c` by 1 since you are increasing count for every 1 time the character is found.

So, your code should become something like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++)
{
    test = word.substring(x, x+1); 
    if (test.equals(character))
    {
        c += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`

Comment: @JigarJoshi Test case please? I didn't test all possible cases, might have missed something. Demo here: http://rextester.com/AFBN6164

Comment: think about last iteration

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. Could you please give an example of the input?